# How can I create a new kind of emblem?

Tags: nautilus, customization, emblem

The emblems in Nautilus don't quite fit my needs. How can I add a new one, just for my user account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Nautilus, go to the *Edit* menu, select *Backgrounds and Emblems*, click on *Emblems*, and then on the *Add a New Emblem* button at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: Oh, now I feel stupid. I've been hacking away at config files trying to figure this out...

Comment: This answer is out-of-date. Newer versions of Nautilus don't support emblems. To work around this, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83226/is-there-any-tweak-to-bring-back-emblems-in-nautilus/

Answer (score 2):

You can also set a custom emblem on a file from a script by running this command:

```
gvfs-set-attribute -t string <filename> metadata::custom-icon file:///home/user/path/to/icon.png
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer really create a custom icon for the object, which is not exactly the same thing an emblem is.

The first answer unfortunately does not work anymore for gnome3. I found that, to create an emblem named for example "mymusic", you can add a png 48x48 image called `emblem-mymusic.png`in the directory:

```
~/.icons/hicolor/48x48/emblems
```

and in the same directory you create a text file, called `emblem-mymusic.icon` with the content:

```
[Icon Data]
DisplayName=mymusic
```

That's it. Now you can set/unset them following the answer to [Is there any tweak to bring back emblems in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83226/is-there-any-tweak-to-bring-back-emblems-in-nautilus/)