# How to Add Emblems to Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a new kind of emblem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41000/how-can-i-create-a-new-kind-of-emblem)

Is there a way to add custom emblems to folders in Nautilus?

The emblems like Music, documents and the check mark on the Ubuntu One folder are very nice and I would like to add a few custom ones.  For example, Audiobook.

Comment: why did that not come up when I was asking the questions.  Well at least I got my answer.

Comment: Note that in Gnome 3 this feature has been removed. See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64300/how-do-i-tag-files-with-custom-emblems-in-nautilus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Nautilus go to *Edit > Backgrounds and Emblems > Emblems > Add a New Emblem*, type a name and choose an icon:

[image]

Close the window, then find and right-click the folder you want to add the new emblem to, and choose *Properties*. In the *Emblems* tab and select your new emblem:

[image]