# Backgrounds & Emblems / Emblems tab disabled?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, emblem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tag files with custom emblems in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64300/how-do-i-tag-files-with-custom-emblems-in-nautilus)

After updating from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10, the `Backgrounds & Emblems` button under `Folder -> Edit` has disappeared. Also, the `Emblems` tab under `Folder -> Properties` has also disappeared.

Folders that already had emblems are still using them, so why can't I access these anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the feature has been removed by gnome3 folks...

http://mail.gnome.org/archives/nautilus-list/2010-July/msg00023.html

[How do I tag files with custom emblems in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64300/how-do-i-tag-files-with-custom-icons-in-nautilus)

that's bad, I don't think people should remove features like thas from software, many people used it a lot...