# What happened to "Backgrounds and Emblems" in Nautilus?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tag files with custom emblems in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64300/how-do-i-tag-files-with-custom-emblems-in-nautilus)

What happened to "Backgrounds and Emblems" in Nautilus.  I installed Ubuntu 11.10 with Nautilus 3.2.1 and there is no longer a way to set backgrounds or add emblems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emblems was removed for the 3.0 release.

> with Nautilus 3.0 around the corner, I went ahead and removed
>   'Backgrounds and Emblems' from nautilus.
>
> There are some reasons for it:
>
> - the code is quite old and crufty, pulls in a lot of libeel code and is basically unmaintained.
> - the feature, as it stands, is not really useful, and it's more cosmetic than anything else, especially now that we use browser mode
>     by default.
> - we're trying to achieve a more streamlined nautilus (see e.g. [1] and [2]), and removing legacy features goes in the right direction.

Reference: http://mail.gnome.org/archives/nautilus-list/2010-July/msg00023.html

Comment: OK, thanks for the prompt reply.  I figured it had to do something with the evolution of Nautilus.  Thanks again for the prompt reply