# How do I add emblems to folders?

Tags: icons, customization, emblem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any tweak to bring back emblems in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83226/is-there-any-tweak-to-bring-back-emblems-in-nautilus)

12.04 home folder icons have small extra figures in the right bottom. Example: the icon for the "Downloads" folder has a small arrow figure. In 10.04 I was able to add these figures to icons of own generated folders. I could do this by right click the icon and these select the small figure I wanted from a pull down list.

How can this be done in 12.04?

Comment: [How do I tag files with custom emblems?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64300/how-do-i-tag-files-with-custom-emblems-in-nautilus) and [Is there any tweak to bring back emblems in Nautilus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83226/is-there-any-tweak-to-bring-back-emblems-in-nautilus/83825#83825)