# Nautilus Action Help - Adding context menu in Nautilus

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any tweak to bring back emblems in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83226/is-there-any-tweak-to-bring-back-emblems-in-nautilus)

I was searching to add emblems support back in ubuntu 12.04 and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/nautilus-emblems/). I also have installed nautilus config tool. There the site says:

---

**Installation and config**

Copy content of Release folder to any location you like, e.g. to /home/user/opt/nautilus-emblems/. Then create custom context menu entry with Nautilus-Actions, and point it to emblems.sh script, passing selected file / folder as a parameter, e.g.:

```
command: /home/user/opt/nautilus-emblems/emblems.sh parameters: %f
```

Script emblems.sh exports LANGUAGE environment variable to set proper locale for an app. It is set to Russian by default, but you may set export LANGUAGE=en_EN:en to use English instead. Other languages aren't included by now.

---

I done that and also got a context menu. But when I click on it noting happens! Please help![image: Action Tab][image: Command Tab]