# Nautilus tags/labels/marks/columns for folders/files

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, directory, nautilus-script, nautilus-extensions

Is there any way how to mark folders or files with tags(or labels, new columns or whatever) in Nautilus? It would be nice to sort marked folders or files through this tags.

Especially my first idea was to mark folders in my Movie directory with tags seen, not seen, must see, and so on. Then I realized it would be useful in any other workspaces with any custom tags...

Is there any nautilus extension for this? Or any other file manager which can do this?

It might look like this:

[image: nautilus custom column/tag]

Comment: Duplicate of this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/83226/is-there-any-tweak-to-bring-back-emblems-in-nautilus/83825#83825

Comment: As I wrote I am familiar with emblems. It is not duplicate of this.

Comment: Then your question is not very clear - you start with "marking", "sorting" and "complicated to assign emblems". Please clarify what you are requesting - pictures would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with extended attributes:

```
setfattr -n user.xdg.label -v "red" file.txt
```