# How to define completely new xdg-user-dirs?

Tags: unity, nautilus, xdg

I've just configured my ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file under unity (ubtuntu 12.10) and everything works well so far. But is there any chance to extend the user dirs like this:

```
XDG_UBUNTUONE_DIR="$HOME/Ubuntu One"
XDG_DROPBOX_DIR="$HOME/Dropbox"
XDG_TEMPORARY_DIR="/media/SYSTEMDATA/Temporary Data"
```

As you can see I want to define completely new entries. How can I define them and e.g. specify icons for those new entries?

THX BKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the lines you suggested, but it won't have any effect. Software needs to be programmed to read those environment variables, and I doubt that Ubuntu One reads `XDG_UBUNTUONE_DIR`, or that Dropbox reads `XDG_DROPBOX_DIR`.

You can, however, specify icons for folders using Nautilus. This used to be a built-in feature of Nautilus, but for the newer versions, you have to install an add-on. See: [Is there any tweak to bring back emblems in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83226/is-there-any-tweak-to-bring-back-emblems-in-nautilus/)

Comment: Yah... it seems to be that everything is hardcoded. But thanks anyway. :)