# how to add an directory to "Places" list

Tags: nautilus

I have directory where it is placed in a deep path. so I want to put that in here:[image]
How I can do that?

Comment: The way I would of done this would of been to edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` - but that doesn't work, and apparently [won't work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/237349/how-to-define-completely-new-xdg-user-dirs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By drag-and-drop**

I'm not sure which file manager you use. I use `thunar`, and there I can just drag and drop folders into the side bar.

**Using `ln -s`**

If that does not work out, use the simple `ln -s /your/long/path/name/here ~/shortname` to create a soft link. It won't show in the side bar, but should be easy to reach via the home folder.