# Renaming Folders using xdg-users-dirs does not work

Tags: 14.04, directory, xdg

I'm attempting to rename my special folders.
As per my understanding, there are two ways to specify this.

1. Local, ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
2. Global, /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults

I've changed both locations to my desired configuration.
But everytime I do xdg-user-dirs-update, it removes all my settings and rewrites it to point to $HOME.

Why is this happening? I can't see anything in the documentation I'm missing.

Would it hurt me just to disable the feature and make my own folders?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename default user directories](http://askubuntu.com/questions/243565/rename-default-user-directories) also [How to define completely new xdg-user-dirs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/237349/how-to-define-completely-new-xdg-user-dirs?rq=1)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a different situation. I've followed both threads, but this keeps happening.

I edit both files to reflect the structure I want. Then I update or relog, and everything is reset to $HOME/.

Comment: Where are your folders located? If they're not accessible/non-existent when you update, the folders will be reset to `$HOME`.

Comment: Do the folders you'd like to use as user dirs already exist? If not, `xdg-user-dirs-update` seems to disable the corresponding user dirs by setting their `$XDG_*_DIR` variables to `$HOME`. So, to fix this, make sure to first create the directories and *then* run `xdg-user-dirs-update`. Then your `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` shouldn't change, either.