# Marking/Tagging a file in Nemo/Nautilus

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, nemo

I'd love a feature in which I can simply mark/tag a file 'Done'(or similar) whenever I'm done with it. If I have a folder full of 200+ files which I need to go through (videos or music), then it would really help if I could just those that I've seen as 'done', or better yet, simply those that I open as 'done'.

Is there any niche extension/script that can do something like this?

Comment: It can be done via [emblems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83226/is-there-any-tweak-to-bring-back-emblems-in-nautilus/83825#83825), prefix, suffix, changing icons, but also it would be rather difficult to mark those most recently accessed considering the nature of atime.

Comment: Wow.. Exact same doubt I had. Well, I cant seem to find such a plugin but a tool that can do this: http://www.tagspaces.org/ See if it solves your problem.